# executing a string as a command in JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a website using HTML. In the js file I have an array of various city names.

I want to store in `sessionStorage` the city name as a key and a number as a value (depending on an if statement). I know I can use for example:

```
sessionStorage.London= 1;
```

but what if I don't know the names before hand or I want to write one line in a loop in order to do that ?

To be clearer, What I want is to be able to do something like:

```
sessionStorage.cityName[i]= 1;
```

Any solution is welcome

Answer (score 1):

If you have dynamic object properties, to which you want to assign values, you can do it like `sessionStorage[ cityName[i] ] = 1;`

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a JSON string in sessionStorage (If I understood your question right):

```
 // Get the session storage cities object:
 var cities = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cities'));

// Set a new city
cities['london'] = 1;

// Save the updated item
 sessionStorage.setItem('cities', JSON.stringify(cities));
```